# changing text inside element script

Tags: events, function, global-variables

I have a script which contains 2 functions.

First function is responsible for creating a paragraph element inside existing div.
Second part of the script is a function which changes the predefined text (the text is predefined in the first function) triggered by onclick event.

HTML:

```
<a href="" onclick="changeText();return false;">Change Text</a>
<div id='box'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var x, el;

    window.onload = function createEl() {

       x = document.getElementById('box');
       el = document.createElement('p');
       el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"));
       x.appendChild(el);
```

}

```
        function changeText() {
              el.innerHTML = 'other text';
        }
```

My question is: Is there any way to achieve the same result but do this without using global variables? I know there should be an option just to pass the variable from one function to another and then update it there, but I am not sure how to do this though

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `p` tag an id and use `document.getElementById` to get it.